# Export to excel not working in jquery datatables when cells contains inverted comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools, datatables-1.10

I am using the jquery datatables in which there is an option for export to excel for which i am using the jquery datatable table tools .My table cells contains inverted comma which is creating problem in exporting.How can i resolve this problem as i have tried to manipulate the data using  **fnCellRender**

```
        "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
               if ( iColumn === 10) {  
    //here i want to check if string contains the inverted comma ,  
//if present then how can i escape them so that they appear in excel too.
                    return sValue;
               }
```

Comment: Shot in the dark here as I can't get to test it but rather than add `'` try `&#39;`. Hope it helps.